# Attachment and Email subject in Outlook using visual basic

Tags: vba, email, outlook, ms-office

I tried to make a standaard email in Outlook with an attachement.
But the results are not quite what i expected.
I get two E-mails.
one mail containing the attachement and the other containing the subject.

```
Sub button()

Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments

Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
myAttachments.Add "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Test.pdf", _
olByValue, 1, "Test"
myItem.Display

Dim oMail As Outlook.mailItem
Dim Item As Outlook.mailItem

Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Set oMail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Reply
Strbody = "HTML"

With oMail
.HTMLBody = Strbody
   .CC = ""
   .BCC = ""
   .Subject = "subject"
   .Display
 End With
End Sub
```

I would like to merge those E-mails together.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new email with attachments and later replying to existing one which creates two mails, try this:

```
Sub button()

    With Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Reply
        .HTMLBody = "HTML"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "subject"
        .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Test.pdf", olByValue, 1, "Test"
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you create a new mail item and a reply to an existing item. Instead you need to create a reply and attach a file there:

```
Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim oMail As Outlook.mailItem
Dim Item As Outlook.mailItem

Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Set oMail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Reply
Strbody = "HTML"

With oMail
  .To = "sadasdasd@sdfsdgfgdfg.com"
  .HTMLBody = Strbody
  .Subject = "subject"
End With

Set myAttachments = oMail.Attachments
myAttachments.Add "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Test.pdf", _
   olByValue, 1, "Test"
oMail.Display
```